# Filtering a SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with a SQL query to show the latest prices with the previous price and the different. I have the below code which shows a price with the previous price using LAG.

```
SELECT
     t.site_id As "Site",
     t.type As "Product",
     t.recorded_time As "Recorded Date",
     t.price / 10 As "Price",
     LAG(t.price) OVER(PARTITION BY t.site_id , t.type  ORDER BY t.recorded_time ) / 10 previous_price,
     LAG(t.recorded_time) OVER(PARTITION BY t.site_id , t.type ORDER BY t.recorded_time ) previous_date,
     (t.price -LAG(t.price) OVER(PARTITION BY t.site_id , t.type  ORDER BY t.recorded_time )) / 10 As "Pricing change"
FROM  table t
```

I have tried adding the below join to just show the records that have the maximum date. However, the three additional columns previous_price, previous_date and Price change are all empty.

```
INNER JOIN( SELECT
         site_id,
         max(recorded_time) as MaxDate,
         type
FROM  table 
GROUP BY site_id,
      type 
) tm ON t.site_id  = tm.site_id
 AND    t.recorded_time  = tm.MaxDate
 AND    t.type  = tm.type
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The join is reducing your results to a single row per site_id and type so there's nothing prior to LAG to

Comment: I think you want to put your original query in a subquery, and then join that subquery to the tm subquery, so the LAG will be calculated prior to the join instead of after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to put your original query in a subquery, and then join that subquery to the tm subquery, so the LAG will be calculated prior to the join instead of after, something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM (
        SELECT
            t.site_id,
            t.type,
            t.recorded_time,
            t.price / 10 As price,
            LAG(t.price) OVER (PARTITION BY t.site_id, t.type ORDER BY t.recorded_time) / 10 previous_price,
            LAG(t.recorded_time) OVER (PARTITION BY t.site_id, t.type ORDER BY t.recorded_time) previous_date,
            (t.price - LAG(t.price) OVER (PARTITION BY t.site_id,t.type ORDER BY t.recorded_time)) / 10 As pricing_change
        FROM
            table
    ) t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            site_id,
            max(recorded_time) as MaxDate,
            type
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY
            site_id,
            type
    ) tm 
        ON t.site_id = tm.site_id
        AND t.recorded_time = tm.MaxDate
        AND t.type = tm.type
```

Comment: Thanks! appreciate your help. this was perfect

Comment: @Sloth87 Glad to help, please accept this answer so I get the points :D